# How to send the left shift key?

Tags: c#, key, shift

I am trying to send a key into another open process in Firefox.
I am supposed to send the Left Shift key, but this is without any luck.

I tried googling these answers but all I end up with were extern methods using nuggets or people using the regular shift. I tried many ways of sending the Left Shift using Enum of the Left Shift or `Sendkey.Send("{LSHIFT}")` and much more but none are working for me. I wish to know if there is any suitable way for me to send the Left Shift key.

This is my code so far:

```
public static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        Keys pressed = (Keys)vkCode;
        MessageBox.Show(pressed.ToString());
        switch (pressed)
        {
            case Keys.Insert:
                {
                    SendKeys.Send("{LSHIFT}");
                }
            break;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I have seen lists with and lists without the left shift key, but either way they pop up as error 'invalid key'.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with `SendKeys`. [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dd6406e8-b6bf-4166-82a0-6d533def38a5/how-to-send-leftright-shift-key?forum=csharpgeneral) might help you.

Comment: I saw this post too, but it does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [keybd_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) API with "VK_LSHIFT" virtual key code :

```
const byte VK_LSHIFT = 0xA0;
const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    keybd_event(VK_LSHIFT, 0, 0, 0);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    keybd_event(VK_LSHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

Comment: Simple side question.. When I send `keybd_event(VK_LSHIFT, 0, 0, 0);`
I insert a regular `SendKeys.Send("a");` which indeed gives me "A"
I am trying this for OEMNUM5, the " | " or " \ ". Though what I need is the backslash, but Key Send doesnt recognise the escape used for backslash
`SendKeys.Send("\\");` and does not send at all. Any ideas?

Comment: @RobertWesterveld Use VK_OEM_102 (0xE2) key code for backslash. and here is list of virtual key code used by the system : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes